# Wifi problems Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager, authentication

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo laptop. Sometimes an error window pops up and shows me that authentication is required for Wi-Fi:

[image: Authentication required popup]

When I hit the *Connect* button it still pops up after a couple of seconds. Mostly this issue is in my home Wi-Fi.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot Router, should connect

Set unused wifi channel, in router, in nearby areas
[ type
nmcli dev wifi
in terminal to find wifi channels in use].

Set wifi channel by logging into router.

If still persists, Reserve ip address for laptop in router lan settings